# How do I change the height of a table row in an SSRS report to hide a subreport?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2014

I am using SSRS 2014 with VS2013 rc5.

Is it possible to change the row heigt forcing `CanShrink` property on a table cell in an SSRS report?

[image: Subreport Section]

I am able to hide the report if the value of the previous column is `0` but how do I shrink the row?

Comment: Is this row a "detail" row in your tablix, where there will be multiple rows, and you only want to change the height of some of them?   If so, I am pretty sure that's not possible.   Why don't you use a Filter on the tablix to not show those rows?

Comment: It is part of the detail for the tablix. As far as filtering the empty rows, I need to have those in there so the page fills with empty rows on a report of say 22 rows max per page (if the row count is less than 22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the height of the row, you just need to hide it.

On your table right click the indicator next to the row and select "Row visibility..."

[image: row visibility menu option]

You can then set to show or hide the row based on an expression. If the row is hidden there won't be any blank space where it should be.